# Cannot validate fields in vue.js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate, vue-validator

I have dynamic fields generated on my form, All the validations that are to be set are retrieved from database (i.e. whether the field is required or optional and numeric value or string are all saved in database), Now when the page is rendered i want to validate my form i'm trying to write my own custom methods but it cannot validate the form,the issue is in custom method error message is not shown and the form is also submitting without validation.

```
<input v-model="field.user_value" :name="field.name" v-on:input="validateTextInput(field.field_validations,$event)" type="text" class="form-control input-md form-control"/>

methods: {
    validateTextInput(validations,event)
    {
      if(validations.req=='required')
      {
       if(event.target.value=='')
       {
         alert('This field is required');
         return false;
       }

       if(validations.allowed=='string')
       {
        
       }


      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the correct variable for the event, use $event instead of e.target.value

```
<input v-model="field.user_value" :name="field.name" v-on:input="validateTextInput(field.field_validations, $event)" type="text" class="form-control input-md form-control"/>

methods: {
    validateTextInput(validations,event)
    {
      if(validations.req=='required')
      {
       if(event.target.value=='')
       {
         alert('This field is required');
         return false;
       }

       if(validations.allowed=='string')
       {
        
       }


      }
```

Comment: I'm getting the value but my issue is how can i show errors and prevent form submit or is there any better way for this type of validation, i have updated my code.

Comment: create a variable under data() for example: "formIsValid: false" and if there is something wrong in any of these fields set it to "this.formIsValid= true" and then listen to the submit event of the form and maybe disable the function take a look at: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html

Comment: Can vuelidate library be used for this type of validation

Comment: probably, if you have enough knowledge.